# Error EmailServicesFunction is invalid or not allowed

Tags: email, emailtosalesforce

IS EmailServicesFunction object is not available for all users of different profiles.

If No, can anyone let me know how to enable this object for all the users.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

EmailServicesFunction components are available in API version 42.0 and later. Please check API version of your Apex class.

Comment: I have created a vf page in which i am using remote objects which is V 43. I am seeing the above object is access to some profiles and some not but not able to get what is the difference in the profile.